# Type '({ options, onSelect }: AtomicDropdownProps) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'FC<AtomicDropdownProps>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

```
import React, { ChangeEvent } from 'react';
import { FormControl, InputLabel, MenuItem, Select } from '@mui/material';
interface AtomicDropdownProps {
  options: string[];
  onSelect: (selectedOption: string) => void;
}
const AtomicDropdown: React.FC<AtomicDropdownProps> = ({ options, onSelect }) => {
  const handleOptionChange = (event: ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
    const selectedValue = event.target.value as string;
    onSelect(selectedValue);
  };
  return (
    <FormControl>
      <InputLabel id="dropdown-label">Language</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="dropdown-label"
        value={''}
        onChange={handleOptionChange}
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
            {option}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
};
export default AtomicDropdown;
```

This code is fine, but still react says

> "Type '({ options, onSelect }: AtomicDropdownProps) => boolean' is not
> assignable to type 'FC'."

Comment: Did you try to simply set the return type to `JSX.Element`?

Comment: Actually i wrongly named file extension .ts instead .tsx, so that's why working code showing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by following solution

Above code only work on .tsx files, I mistakenly writen above working code on a .ts file. If you faced same issue, please confirm the file extension in first step.